# Batch script : Echo is not printing the variable value

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script:

```
echo on
Set appdir=This is testing for substring : Management\s18vx
ECHO %appdir%

REM get substring i.e, s18vx
Set SubStr = %appdir:~43%
ECHO %SubStr%

cmd /k
```

After getting the sub string, I am setting it to new variable. On Echo on this variable prints nothing. Not sure what is going wrong here. Basically I want to populate the new variable with extracted string i.e, s18vx in this case.

[image]

Comment: Either use `ECHO %SubStr %` to match the name you've set for the variable, or use the correct syntax to `Set` the variable in the first instance, i.e. `Set "SubStr=%appdir:~43%"`, followed by `ECHO %SubStr%` as before. As a side note, I'd probably consider using `Set "SubStr=%appdir:*\=%"` instead.

Comment: @Compo Regarding the side note part. What happens if in his real world scenario the string becomes `Set "appdir=C:\apps\documents\s18vx"` if this string is in fact the case as per his example, then that option is 100% better, but I suspect OP might be using an actual path. :)

Comment: @Gerhard, I see what you're thinking, and if that were the case, I'd suggest parsing it as a normal file folder path, and using the appropriate modifier, e.g. `%~nxI`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this one a go:

```
@echo off
set "appdir=This is testing for substring : Management\s18vx"
echo %appdir%

REM get substring i.e, s18vx
Set "SubStr=%appdir:~43%"
echo %SubStr%
pause
```

The Spaces before and after `=` is really not wanted it here. This will create a variable name with a trialing space and a value with a leading space, i.e: `set variable = value` will therefore become `%variable %` and  `value`.

Also wrap your variables in double quotes to eliminate additional whitespace, especially after the variable string.

For more help on the `set` command, open `cmd.exe` and type `set /?`

Some side notes:
Echo is on by default, unless this forms part of a script where echo is turned off earlier and you want to turn it on for some reason, you do not need to switch it on.

Also, I suggest if you want an end result only to turn `@echo off` because `echo on` is almost like a debug function, it `echo`s each of the commands you run, where `echo off` will disable this and display the end result only.

Comment: Plus one for the "spacing in =" comment. Was causing me all sorts of trouble.

Comment: Thanks, @Jacques, I edited to make it a little clearer as well. (fellow South African)